# I want to optimize code, and don't know which constructor I should make

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

I want to optimize code, and don't know which constructor I should make

```
CATEGORIES = [«0»,«1»,«2»,«3»,«4»,«5»,«6»,«7»,«8»,«9»,«A»,«B»,«C»,«D»,«E»,«F»,«G»,«H»,«I»,«J»,«K»,«L»,«M»,«N»,«O»,«P»,«R»,«S»,«T»,«U»,«V»,«W»,«X»,«Y»,«Z»]

DATA = [[0.002,0.006,0.004,0.045,0.002,0.017,0.006,0.077,0.001,0.035,0.042,0.005,0.004,0.039,0.001,0.002,0.001,0.008,0.058,0.352,0.002,0.007,0.017,0.004,0.007,0.007,0.007,0.004,0.005,0.009,0.089,0.036,0.053,0.041,0.004],[0.003,0.007,0.005,0.075,0.001,0.020,0.006,0.044,0.002,0.035,0.026,0.004,0.004,0.033,0.001,0.001,0.003,0.008,0.049,0.360,0.002,0.007,0.021,0.005,0.009,0.003,0.008,0.007,0.003,0.014,0.092,0.048,0.058,0.031,0.004],[0.002,0.000,0.025,0.012,0.006,0.002,0.001,0.627,0.006,0.021,0.022,0.008,0.004,0.006,0.004,0.033,0.000,0.006,0.011,0.009,0.002,0.002,0.009,0.000,0.002,0.040,0.007,0.005,0.015,0.000,0.035,0.001,0.008,0.015,0.053],[0.056,0.008,0.023,0.038,0.015,0.007,0.050,0.006,0.412,0.004,0.005,0.027,0.011,0.005,0.021,0.007,0.073,0.024,0.012,0.005,0.013,0.005,0.027,0.003,0.015,0.001,0.005,0.074,0.002,0.022,0.005,0.011,0.002,0.001,0.006],[0.025,0.011,0.025,0.034,0.018,0.027,0.090,0.008,0.258,0.006,0.007,0.026,0.016,0.008,0.026,0.011,0.079,0.030,0.026,0.008,0.018,0.011,0.033,0.003,0.016,0.001,0.003,0.106,0.004,0.021,0.012,0.013,0.003,0.005,0.014],[0.048,0.027,0.019,0.002,0.028,0.002,0.008,0.017,0.041,0.014,0.012,0.022,0.031,0.005,0.045,0.100,0.004,0.031,0.033,0.002,0.029,0.006,0.021,0.032,0.008,0.038,0.317,0.007,0.017,0.004,0.018,0.005,0.003,0.004,0.002],[0.013,0.002,0.002,0.000,0.164,0.001,0.060,0.004,0.006,0.002,0.018,0.003,0.035,0.002,0.008,0.008,0.001,0.008,0.028,0.005,0.383,0.013,0.063,0.010,0.004,0.002,0.014,0.016,0.002,0.005,0.048,0.011,0.028,0.017,0.012]]

KR8877J_1 = [[0.004,0.007,0.005,0.042,0.002,0.014,0.011,0.054,0.002,0.032,0.051,0.005,0.005,0.044,0.001,0.002,0.002,0.008,0.056,0.389,0.003,0.008,0.023,0.005,0.009,0.005,0.009,0.006,0.004,0.010,0.070,0.029,0.049,0.031,0.005],[0.005,0.005,0.005,0.034,0.002,0.006,0.005,0.083,0.002,0.062,0.053,0.004,0.006,0.039,0.001,0.002,0.001,0.008,0.055,0.348,0.002,0.005,0.020,0.005,0.011,0.011,0.018,0.004,0.005,0.008,0.086,0.018,0.055,0.020,0.004],[0.001,0.001,0.024,0.009,0.013,0.003,0.002,0.499,0.006,0.011,0.022,0.011,0.007,0.006,0.006,0.048,0.000,0.008,0.013,0.009,0.004,0.002,0.007,0.000,0.002,0.053,0.009,0.007,0.030,0.000,0.030,0.001,0.009,0.021,0.123],[0.039,0.008,0.029,0.041,0.013,0.008,0.054,0.005,0.369,0.004,0.005,0.023,0.011,0.005,0.020,0.005,0.100,0.022,0.012,0.005,0.012,0.007,0.028,0.002,0.015,0.000,0.003,0.102,0.001,0.021,0.006,0.012,0.002,0.002,0.007],[0.031,0.007,0.018,0.032,0.015,0.017,0.075,0.008,0.365,0.005,0.005,0.028,0.015,0.005,0.022,0.011,0.075,0.027,0.014,0.005,0.020,0.006,0.025,0.002,0.014,0.001,0.004,0.099,0.003,0.016,0.008,0.009,0.002,0.002,0.010],[0.046,0.022,0.022,0.002,0.031,0.003,0.008,0.022,0.047,0.011,0.010,0.039,0.035,0.005,0.048,0.110,0.002,0.028,0.031,0.003,0.029,0.006,0.016,0.022,0.007,0.059,0.289,0.005,0.016,0.003,0.013,0.004,0.002,0.004,0.003],[0.019,0.004,0.002,0.000,0.134,0.004,0.088,0.006,0.004,0.003,0.016,0.007,0.037,0.004,0.016,0.014,0.002,0.014,0.026,0.005,0.342,0.019,0.049,0.024,0.004,0.003,0.021,0.009,0.005,0.009,0.049,0.012,0.017,0.026,0.006]]

KR8877J_2 = [[0.002,0.005,0.005,0.046,0.002,0.014,0.008,0.073,0.002,0.023,0.042,0.004,0.007,0.027,0.001,0.003,0.001,0.006,0.047,0.384,0.005,0.006,0.015,0.003,0.006,0.004,0.011,0.006,0.006,0.005,0.088,0.027,0.066,0.040,0.010],[0.002,0.005,0.005,0.039,0.002,0.009,0.005,0.089,0.001,0.036,0.043,0.004,0.006,0.026,0.001,0.002,0.001,0.006,0.051,0.387,0.003,0.005,0.014,0.003,0.007,0.007,0.014,0.004,0.007,0.005,0.090,0.022,0.064,0.030,0.006],[0.002,0.001,0.014,0.011,0.020,0.005,0.004,0.282,0.005,0.012,0.022,0.011,0.009,0.010,0.008,0.041,0.000,0.017,0.030,0.019,0.009,0.003,0.009,0.000,0.004,0.053,0.010,0.016,0.049,0.000,0.043,0.002,0.017,0.037,0.224],[0.028,0.015,0.029,0.039,0.023,0.020,0.097,0.008,0.239,0.004,0.009,0.021,0.019,0.008,0.017,0.008,0.082,0.023,0.025,0.012,0.020,0.010,0.037,0.003,0.016,0.001,0.003,0.110,0.003,0.019,0.012,0.014,0.004,0.005,0.015],[0.037,0.013,0.035,0.053,0.025,0.022,0.057,0.017,0.250,0.005,0.009,0.037,0.025,0.008,0.029,0.013,0.057,0.029,0.029,0.009,0.015,0.009,0.027,0.002,0.020,0.002,0.006,0.092,0.006,0.012,0.011,0.011,0.003,0.004,0.021],[0.036,0.022,0.024,0.003,0.022,0.004,0.011,0.019,0.069,0.014,0.011,0.035,0.045,0.006,0.057,0.096,0.004,0.037,0.030,0.004,0.039,0.007,0.021,0.018,0.010,0.031,0.256,0.013,0.018,0.003,0.018,0.005,0.004,0.006,0.004],[0.015,0.003,0.002,0.000,0.174,0.004,0.085,0.008,0.005,0.002,0.015,0.008,0.028,0.003,0.013,0.016,0.001,0.015,0.029,0.004,0.357,0.013,0.043,0.017,0.003,0.003,0.017,0.010,0.004,0.007,0.037,0.013,0.015,0.020,0.010]]

KR8877J_3 = [[0.005,0.006,0.006,0.055,0.002,0.017,0.009,0.076,0.003,0.035,0.032,0.007,0.005,0.050,0.001,0.002,0.002,0.011,0.050,0.391,0.002,0.005,0.018,0.003,0.012,0.009,0.009,0.005,0.005,0.012,0.068,0.032,0.032,0.017,0.006],[0.009,0.005,0.007,0.064,0.002,0.022,0.009,0.040,0.003,0.030,0.026,0.010,0.006,0.069,0.001,0.001,0.004,0.011,0.040,0.379,0.002,0.009,0.021,0.005,0.017,0.007,0.009,0.005,0.003,0.034,0.063,0.035,0.029,0.017,0.006],[0.001,0.001,0.014,0.011,0.011,0.004,0.003,0.458,0.004,0.012,0.023,0.010,0.007,0.009,0.006,0.039,0.000,0.012,0.016,0.014,0.005,0.003,0.007,0.000,0.002,0.052,0.008,0.009,0.039,0.000,0.036,0.001,0.013,0.032,0.139],[0.042,0.012,0.023,0.029,0.043,0.015,0.111,0.010,0.235,0.004,0.009,0.036,0.023,0.010,0.018,0.010,0.039,0.029,0.024,0.012,0.025,0.009,0.041,0.003,0.019,0.002,0.005,0.084,0.004,0.018,0.013,0.012,0.004,0.005,0.023],[0.030,0.008,0.017,0.033,0.011,0.020,0.103,0.009,0.289,0.004,0.006,0.030,0.022,0.007,0.021,0.011,0.108,0.031,0.013,0.008,0.020,0.006,0.023,0.002,0.018,0.001,0.004,0.102,0.005,0.012,0.007,0.007,0.002,0.003,0.009],[0.034,0.024,0.018,0.003,0.025,0.005,0.008,0.025,0.053,0.010,0.008,0.045,0.036,0.006,0.050,0.119,0.002,0.035,0.028,0.003,0.029,0.005,0.014,0.017,0.007,0.060,0.275,0.006,0.019,0.002,0.013,0.004,0.003,0.006,0.005],[0.016,0.004,0.002,0.000,0.130,0.003,0.080,0.005,0.004,0.003,0.017,0.005,0.038,0.002,0.015,0.014,0.002,0.011,0.027,0.004,0.378,0.016,0.051,0.019,0.004,0.002,0.020,0.012,0.004,0.006,0.040,0.013,0.023,0.020,0.008]]

KR8877J_4 = [[0.006,0.004,0.007,0.052,0.002,0.012,0.005,0.066,0.002,0.043,0.036,0.007,0.007,0.051,0.001,0.001,0.002,0.008,0.037,0.401,0.002,0.008,0.017,0.004,0.013,0.010,0.014,0.004,0.004,0.016,0.077,0.021,0.038,0.018,0.006],[0.001,0.001,0.012,0.008,0.013,0.004,0.002,0.462,0.004,0.011,0.022,0.008,0.006,0.006,0.006,0.052,0.000,0.012,0.018,0.012,0.005,0.002,0.007,0.000,0.002,0.046,0.009,0.009,0.040,0.000,0.039,0.002,0.012,0.031,0.136],[0.004,0.003,0.007,0.042,0.001,0.008,0.005,0.060,0.002,0.062,0.050,0.005,0.004,0.053,0.000,0.001,0.002,0.006,0.033,0.422,0.001,0.008,0.017,0.004,0.011,0.007,0.010,0.003,0.002,0.013,0.065,0.024,0.045,0.017,0.003],[0.029,0.015,0.032,0.058,0.018,0.013,0.067,0.012,0.287,0.006,0.010,0.025,0.016,0.007,0.017,0.009,0.059,0.023,0.026,0.011,0.016,0.006,0.033,0.003,0.017,0.001,0.006,0.118,0.004,0.014,0.009,0.012,0.004,0.003,0.012],[0.056,0.011,0.024,0.034,0.027,0.015,0.065,0.013,0.271,0.006,0.007,0.062,0.028,0.013,0.026,0.014,0.030,0.039,0.027,0.011,0.019,0.006,0.031,0.003,0.027,0.005,0.009,0.061,0.006,0.014,0.011,0.006,0.002,0.004,0.016],[0.041,0.020,0.022,0.002,0.019,0.004,0.007,0.024,0.046,0.016,0.008,0.051,0.036,0.006,0.051,0.109,0.002,0.030,0.027,0.003,0.024,0.005,0.015,0.017,0.008,0.067,0.286,0.005,0.015,0.003,0.014,0.003,0.002,0.005,0.003],[0.014,0.003,0.002,0.000,0.106,0.007,0.079,0.007,0.004,0.003,0.014,0.010,0.041,0.004,0.013,0.011,0.001,0.014,0.031,0.007,0.377,0.022,0.049,0.017,0.004,0.003,0.014,0.009,0.004,0.009,0.050,0.013,0.016,0.034,0.008]]

KR8877J_5 = [[0.008,0.004,0.008,0.064,0.001,0.018,0.009,0.041,0.003,0.043,0.035,0.008,0.005,0.076,0.001,0.001,0.004,0.009,0.037,0.382,0.001,0.011,0.024,0.005,0.015,0.006,0.007,0.005,0.002,0.030,0.057,0.031,0.029,0.017,0.004],[0.002,0.004,0.004,0.044,0.001,0.012,0.005,0.068,0.001,0.043,0.052,0.003,0.005,0.030,0.001,0.002,0.001,0.007,0.041,0.350,0.003,0.007,0.019,0.005,0.007,0.004,0.011,0.005,0.003,0.007,0.099,0.035,0.076,0.038,0.004],[0.001,0.001,0.015,0.011,0.009,0.004,0.002,0.517,0.004,0.012,0.028,0.007,0.005,0.007,0.005,0.035,0.000,0.011,0.014,0.012,0.005,0.003,0.010,0.000,0.002,0.030,0.006,0.009,0.029,0.000,0.039,0.002,0.016,0.034,0.114],[0.026,0.010,0.036,0.064,0.011,0.009,0.052,0.010,0.360,0.004,0.007,0.022,0.015,0.005,0.017,0.006,0.067,0.019,0.017,0.008,0.013,0.006,0.026,0.002,0.015,0.001,0.004,0.121,0.003,0.011,0.006,0.010,0.003,0.002,0.011],[0.044,0.017,0.027,0.037,0.024,0.016,0.079,0.010,0.259,0.006,0.009,0.032,0.023,0.009,0.022,0.012,0.064,0.031,0.026,0.010,0.019,0.007,0.034,0.004,0.021,0.002,0.007,0.086,0.005,0.018,0.011,0.011,0.003,0.003,0.011],[0.033,0.013,0.021,0.002,0.014,0.003,0.006,0.023,0.033,0.015,0.009,0.048,0.040,0.007,0.056,0.098,0.002,0.032,0.023,0.003,0.023,0.006,0.013,0.015,0.009,0.069,0.331,0.005,0.018,0.002,0.012,0.003,0.002,0.005,0.003],[0.017,0.004,0.002,0.000,0.096,0.008,0.095,0.007,0.004,0.003,0.013,0.012,0.045,0.006,0.017,0.013,0.002,0.016,0.029,0.007,0.360,0.023,0.045,0.023,0.005,0.004,0.018,0.008,0.005,0.010,0.042,0.011,0.013,0.032,0.007]]

KR8877J_6 = [[0.007,0.004,0.007,0.082,0.002,0.023,0.009,0.029,0.003,0.024,0.024,0.008,0.006,0.062,0.001,0.001,0.005,0.009,0.032,0.391,0.002,0.012,0.020,0.005,0.016,0.004,0.006,0.006,0.002,0.037,0.061,0.041,0.033,0.019,0.006],[0.004,0.004,0.008,0.078,0.001,0.013,0.005,0.059,0.002,0.044,0.041,0.006,0.005,0.052,0.001,0.001,0.002,0.008,0.036,0.366,0.001,0.010,0.015,0.003,0.011,0.008,0.008,0.005,0.004,0.015,0.074,0.035,0.045,0.023,0.007],[0.001,0.001,0.013,0.010,0.015,0.006,0.004,0.299,0.004,0.011,0.021,0.011,0.009,0.010,0.009,0.044,0.000,0.021,0.023,0.017,0.008,0.004,0.007,0.000,0.003,0.056,0.008,0.014,0.056,0.000,0.040,0.002,0.016,0.039,0.217],[0.021,0.011,0.022,0.060,0.018,0.026,0.090,0.014,0.234,0.005,0.011,0.025,0.016,0.009,0.015,0.011,0.052,0.030,0.029,0.015,0.019,0.007,0.030,0.003,0.016,0.001,0.003,0.134,0.006,0.013,0.011,0.014,0.004,0.005,0.020],[0.031,0.012,0.027,0.036,0.023,0.020,0.053,0.018,0.269,0.006,0.008,0.029,0.036,0.007,0.029,0.021,0.046,0.030,0.028,0.009,0.023,0.007,0.027,0.003,0.020,0.002,0.010,0.098,0.010,0.009,0.016,0.009,0.004,0.005,0.018],[0.036,0.019,0.017,0.002,0.027,0.004,0.009,0.027,0.063,0.012,0.008,0.045,0.035,0.006,0.050,0.140,0.002,0.036,0.030,0.003,0.031,0.004,0.017,0.016,0.007,0.055,0.239,0.007,0.018,0.002,0.014,0.004,0.003,0.006,0.004],[0.018,0.004,0.002,0.000,0.186,0.004,0.107,0.005,0.005,0.003,0.010,0.008,0.041,0.004,0.017,0.018,0.001,0.012,0.034,0.004,0.300,0.014,0.036,0.018,0.004,0.004,0.020,0.010,0.005,0.008,0.049,0.009,0.011,0.020,0.008]]

def readable(): #start = time.time() tags = [] for lst in DATA: index = max(enumerate(lst), key=lambda pair: pair[1])[0] tags.append(CATEGORIES[index]) tags.reverse() print(tags)

tags1 = []
for lst1 in KR8877J_1:
    index = max(enumerate(lst1), key=lambda pair: pair[1])[0]
    tags1.append(CATEGORIES[index])
tags1.reverse()
print(tags)

tags2 = []
for lst2 in KR8877J_2:
    index = max(enumerate(lst2), key=lambda pair: pair[1])[0]
    tags2.append(CATEGORIES[index])
tags2.reverse()
print(tags2)

tags3 = []
for lst3 in KR8877J_3:
    index = max(enumerate(lst3), key=lambda pair: pair[1])[0]
    tags3.append(CATEGORIES[index])
tags3.reverse()
print(tags3)


tags4 = []
for lst4 in KR8877J_4:
    index = max(enumerate(lst4), key=lambda pair: pair[1])[0]
    tags4.append(CATEGORIES[index])
tags4.reverse()
print(tags4)


tags5 = []
for lst5 in KR8877J_5:
    index = max(enumerate(lst5), key=lambda pair: pair[1])[0]
    tags5.append(CATEGORIES[index])
tags5.reverse()
print(tags5)

tags6 = []
for lst6 in KR8877J_6:
    index = max(enumerate(lst6), key=lambda pair: pair[1])[0]
    tags6.append(CATEGORIES[index])
tags6.reverse()
print(tags6)
```

output in terminal is [‘K’, ‘R’, ‘8’, ‘8’, ‘7’, ‘J’, ‘J’] [‘K’, ‘R’, ‘8’, ‘8’, ‘7’, ‘J’, ‘J’] [‘K’, ‘R’, ‘8’, ‘8’, ‘7’, ‘J’, ‘J’] [‘K’, ‘R’, ‘8’, ‘8’, ‘7’, ‘J’, ‘J’] [‘K’, ‘R’, ‘8’, ‘8’, ‘J’, ‘7’, ‘J’] [‘K’, ‘R’, ‘8’, ‘8’, ‘7’, ‘J’, ‘J’] [‘K’, ‘R’, ‘8’, ‘8’, ‘7’, ‘J’, ‘J’]

I want to make a constructor or method to handle the data.
Is it possible to make all these data: DATA, KR8877J_1, KR8877J_3, etc. in the list?
I need the maximum average values in this case it will be KR88JJ.
Thank you all in advance!

Comment: the first line gives an error ```SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CATEGORIES = [«0»,«1»,«2»,«3»,«4»,«5»,«6»,«7»,«8»,«9»,«A»,«B»,«C»,«D»,«E»,«F»,«G»,«H»,«I»,«J»,«K»,«L»,«M»,«N»,«O»,«P»,«R»,«S»,«T»,«U»,«V»,«W»,«X»,«Y»,«Z»]

DATA = [[0.002,0.006,0.004,0.045,0.002,0.017,0.006,0.077,0.001,0.035,0.042,0.005,0.004,0.039,0.001,0.002,0.001,0.008,0.058,0.352,0.002,0.007,0.017,0.004,0.007,0.007,0.007,0.004,0.005,0.009,0.089,0.036,0.053,0.041,0.004],[0.003,0.007,0.005,0.075,0.001,0.020,0.006,0.044,0.002,0.035,0.026,0.004,0.004,0.033,0.001,0.001,0.003,0.008,0.049,0.360,0.002,0.007,0.021,0.005,0.009,0.003,0.008,0.007,0.003,0.014,0.092,0.048,0.058,0.031,0.004],[0.002,0.000,0.025,0.012,0.006,0.002,0.001,0.627,0.006,0.021,0.022,0.008,0.004,0.006,0.004,0.033,0.000,0.006,0.011,0.009,0.002,0.002,0.009,0.000,0.002,0.040,0.007,0.005,0.015,0.000,0.035,0.001,0.008,0.015,0.053],[0.056,0.008,0.023,0.038,0.015,0.007,0.050,0.006,0.412,0.004,0.005,0.027,0.011,0.005,0.021,0.007,0.073,0.024,0.012,0.005,0.013,0.005,0.027,0.003,0.015,0.001,0.005,0.074,0.002,0.022,0.005,0.011,0.002,0.001,0.006],[0.025,0.011,0.025,0.034,0.018,0.027,0.090,0.008,0.258,0.006,0.007,0.026,0.016,0.008,0.026,0.011,0.079,0.030,0.026,0.008,0.018,0.011,0.033,0.003,0.016,0.001,0.003,0.106,0.004,0.021,0.012,0.013,0.003,0.005,0.014],[0.048,0.027,0.019,0.002,0.028,0.002,0.008,0.017,0.041,0.014,0.012,0.022,0.031,0.005,0.045,0.100,0.004,0.031,0.033,0.002,0.029,0.006,0.021,0.032,0.008,0.038,0.317,0.007,0.017,0.004,0.018,0.005,0.003,0.004,0.002],[0.013,0.002,0.002,0.000,0.164,0.001,0.060,0.004,0.006,0.002,0.018,0.003,0.035,0.002,0.008,0.008,0.001,0.008,0.028,0.005,0.383,0.013,0.063,0.010,0.004,0.002,0.014,0.016,0.002,0.005,0.048,0.011,0.028,0.017,0.012]]

KR8877J_1 = [[0.004,0.007,0.005,0.042,0.002,0.014,0.011,0.054,0.002,0.032,0.051,0.005,0.005,0.044,0.001,0.002,0.002,0.008,0.056,0.389,0.003,0.008,0.023,0.005,0.009,0.005,0.009,0.006,0.004,0.010,0.070,0.029,0.049,0.031,0.005],[0.005,0.005,0.005,0.034,0.002,0.006,0.005,0.083,0.002,0.062,0.053,0.004,0.006,0.039,0.001,0.002,0.001,0.008,0.055,0.348,0.002,0.005,0.020,0.005,0.011,0.011,0.018,0.004,0.005,0.008,0.086,0.018,0.055,0.020,0.004],[0.001,0.001,0.024,0.009,0.013,0.003,0.002,0.499,0.006,0.011,0.022,0.011,0.007,0.006,0.006,0.048,0.000,0.008,0.013,0.009,0.004,0.002,0.007,0.000,0.002,0.053,0.009,0.007,0.030,0.000,0.030,0.001,0.009,0.021,0.123],[0.039,0.008,0.029,0.041,0.013,0.008,0.054,0.005,0.369,0.004,0.005,0.023,0.011,0.005,0.020,0.005,0.100,0.022,0.012,0.005,0.012,0.007,0.028,0.002,0.015,0.000,0.003,0.102,0.001,0.021,0.006,0.012,0.002,0.002,0.007],[0.031,0.007,0.018,0.032,0.015,0.017,0.075,0.008,0.365,0.005,0.005,0.028,0.015,0.005,0.022,0.011,0.075,0.027,0.014,0.005,0.020,0.006,0.025,0.002,0.014,0.001,0.004,0.099,0.003,0.016,0.008,0.009,0.002,0.002,0.010],[0.046,0.022,0.022,0.002,0.031,0.003,0.008,0.022,0.047,0.011,0.010,0.039,0.035,0.005,0.048,0.110,0.002,0.028,0.031,0.003,0.029,0.006,0.016,0.022,0.007,0.059,0.289,0.005,0.016,0.003,0.013,0.004,0.002,0.004,0.003],[0.019,0.004,0.002,0.000,0.134,0.004,0.088,0.006,0.004,0.003,0.016,0.007,0.037,0.004,0.016,0.014,0.002,0.014,0.026,0.005,0.342,0.019,0.049,0.024,0.004,0.003,0.021,0.009,0.005,0.009,0.049,0.012,0.017,0.026,0.006]]

KR8877J_2 = [[0.002,0.005,0.005,0.046,0.002,0.014,0.008,0.073,0.002,0.023,0.042,0.004,0.007,0.027,0.001,0.003,0.001,0.006,0.047,0.384,0.005,0.006,0.015,0.003,0.006,0.004,0.011,0.006,0.006,0.005,0.088,0.027,0.066,0.040,0.010],[0.002,0.005,0.005,0.039,0.002,0.009,0.005,0.089,0.001,0.036,0.043,0.004,0.006,0.026,0.001,0.002,0.001,0.006,0.051,0.387,0.003,0.005,0.014,0.003,0.007,0.007,0.014,0.004,0.007,0.005,0.090,0.022,0.064,0.030,0.006],[0.002,0.001,0.014,0.011,0.020,0.005,0.004,0.282,0.005,0.012,0.022,0.011,0.009,0.010,0.008,0.041,0.000,0.017,0.030,0.019,0.009,0.003,0.009,0.000,0.004,0.053,0.010,0.016,0.049,0.000,0.043,0.002,0.017,0.037,0.224],[0.028,0.015,0.029,0.039,0.023,0.020,0.097,0.008,0.239,0.004,0.009,0.021,0.019,0.008,0.017,0.008,0.082,0.023,0.025,0.012,0.020,0.010,0.037,0.003,0.016,0.001,0.003,0.110,0.003,0.019,0.012,0.014,0.004,0.005,0.015],[0.037,0.013,0.035,0.053,0.025,0.022,0.057,0.017,0.250,0.005,0.009,0.037,0.025,0.008,0.029,0.013,0.057,0.029,0.029,0.009,0.015,0.009,0.027,0.002,0.020,0.002,0.006,0.092,0.006,0.012,0.011,0.011,0.003,0.004,0.021],[0.036,0.022,0.024,0.003,0.022,0.004,0.011,0.019,0.069,0.014,0.011,0.035,0.045,0.006,0.057,0.096,0.004,0.037,0.030,0.004,0.039,0.007,0.021,0.018,0.010,0.031,0.256,0.013,0.018,0.003,0.018,0.005,0.004,0.006,0.004],[0.015,0.003,0.002,0.000,0.174,0.004,0.085,0.008,0.005,0.002,0.015,0.008,0.028,0.003,0.013,0.016,0.001,0.015,0.029,0.004,0.357,0.013,0.043,0.017,0.003,0.003,0.017,0.010,0.004,0.007,0.037,0.013,0.015,0.020,0.010]]

KR8877J_3 = [[0.005,0.006,0.006,0.055,0.002,0.017,0.009,0.076,0.003,0.035,0.032,0.007,0.005,0.050,0.001,0.002,0.002,0.011,0.050,0.391,0.002,0.005,0.018,0.003,0.012,0.009,0.009,0.005,0.005,0.012,0.068,0.032,0.032,0.017,0.006],[0.009,0.005,0.007,0.064,0.002,0.022,0.009,0.040,0.003,0.030,0.026,0.010,0.006,0.069,0.001,0.001,0.004,0.011,0.040,0.379,0.002,0.009,0.021,0.005,0.017,0.007,0.009,0.005,0.003,0.034,0.063,0.035,0.029,0.017,0.006],[0.001,0.001,0.014,0.011,0.011,0.004,0.003,0.458,0.004,0.012,0.023,0.010,0.007,0.009,0.006,0.039,0.000,0.012,0.016,0.014,0.005,0.003,0.007,0.000,0.002,0.052,0.008,0.009,0.039,0.000,0.036,0.001,0.013,0.032,0.139],[0.042,0.012,0.023,0.029,0.043,0.015,0.111,0.010,0.235,0.004,0.009,0.036,0.023,0.010,0.018,0.010,0.039,0.029,0.024,0.012,0.025,0.009,0.041,0.003,0.019,0.002,0.005,0.084,0.004,0.018,0.013,0.012,0.004,0.005,0.023],[0.030,0.008,0.017,0.033,0.011,0.020,0.103,0.009,0.289,0.004,0.006,0.030,0.022,0.007,0.021,0.011,0.108,0.031,0.013,0.008,0.020,0.006,0.023,0.002,0.018,0.001,0.004,0.102,0.005,0.012,0.007,0.007,0.002,0.003,0.009],[0.034,0.024,0.018,0.003,0.025,0.005,0.008,0.025,0.053,0.010,0.008,0.045,0.036,0.006,0.050,0.119,0.002,0.035,0.028,0.003,0.029,0.005,0.014,0.017,0.007,0.060,0.275,0.006,0.019,0.002,0.013,0.004,0.003,0.006,0.005],[0.016,0.004,0.002,0.000,0.130,0.003,0.080,0.005,0.004,0.003,0.017,0.005,0.038,0.002,0.015,0.014,0.002,0.011,0.027,0.004,0.378,0.016,0.051,0.019,0.004,0.002,0.020,0.012,0.004,0.006,0.040,0.013,0.023,0.020,0.008]]

KR8877J_4 = [[0.006,0.004,0.007,0.052,0.002,0.012,0.005,0.066,0.002,0.043,0.036,0.007,0.007,0.051,0.001,0.001,0.002,0.008,0.037,0.401,0.002,0.008,0.017,0.004,0.013,0.010,0.014,0.004,0.004,0.016,0.077,0.021,0.038,0.018,0.006],[0.001,0.001,0.012,0.008,0.013,0.004,0.002,0.462,0.004,0.011,0.022,0.008,0.006,0.006,0.006,0.052,0.000,0.012,0.018,0.012,0.005,0.002,0.007,0.000,0.002,0.046,0.009,0.009,0.040,0.000,0.039,0.002,0.012,0.031,0.136],[0.004,0.003,0.007,0.042,0.001,0.008,0.005,0.060,0.002,0.062,0.050,0.005,0.004,0.053,0.000,0.001,0.002,0.006,0.033,0.422,0.001,0.008,0.017,0.004,0.011,0.007,0.010,0.003,0.002,0.013,0.065,0.024,0.045,0.017,0.003],[0.029,0.015,0.032,0.058,0.018,0.013,0.067,0.012,0.287,0.006,0.010,0.025,0.016,0.007,0.017,0.009,0.059,0.023,0.026,0.011,0.016,0.006,0.033,0.003,0.017,0.001,0.006,0.118,0.004,0.014,0.009,0.012,0.004,0.003,0.012],[0.056,0.011,0.024,0.034,0.027,0.015,0.065,0.013,0.271,0.006,0.007,0.062,0.028,0.013,0.026,0.014,0.030,0.039,0.027,0.011,0.019,0.006,0.031,0.003,0.027,0.005,0.009,0.061,0.006,0.014,0.011,0.006,0.002,0.004,0.016],[0.041,0.020,0.022,0.002,0.019,0.004,0.007,0.024,0.046,0.016,0.008,0.051,0.036,0.006,0.051,0.109,0.002,0.030,0.027,0.003,0.024,0.005,0.015,0.017,0.008,0.067,0.286,0.005,0.015,0.003,0.014,0.003,0.002,0.005,0.003],[0.014,0.003,0.002,0.000,0.106,0.007,0.079,0.007,0.004,0.003,0.014,0.010,0.041,0.004,0.013,0.011,0.001,0.014,0.031,0.007,0.377,0.022,0.049,0.017,0.004,0.003,0.014,0.009,0.004,0.009,0.050,0.013,0.016,0.034,0.008]]

KR8877J_5 = [[0.008,0.004,0.008,0.064,0.001,0.018,0.009,0.041,0.003,0.043,0.035,0.008,0.005,0.076,0.001,0.001,0.004,0.009,0.037,0.382,0.001,0.011,0.024,0.005,0.015,0.006,0.007,0.005,0.002,0.030,0.057,0.031,0.029,0.017,0.004],[0.002,0.004,0.004,0.044,0.001,0.012,0.005,0.068,0.001,0.043,0.052,0.003,0.005,0.030,0.001,0.002,0.001,0.007,0.041,0.350,0.003,0.007,0.019,0.005,0.007,0.004,0.011,0.005,0.003,0.007,0.099,0.035,0.076,0.038,0.004],[0.001,0.001,0.015,0.011,0.009,0.004,0.002,0.517,0.004,0.012,0.028,0.007,0.005,0.007,0.005,0.035,0.000,0.011,0.014,0.012,0.005,0.003,0.010,0.000,0.002,0.030,0.006,0.009,0.029,0.000,0.039,0.002,0.016,0.034,0.114],[0.026,0.010,0.036,0.064,0.011,0.009,0.052,0.010,0.360,0.004,0.007,0.022,0.015,0.005,0.017,0.006,0.067,0.019,0.017,0.008,0.013,0.006,0.026,0.002,0.015,0.001,0.004,0.121,0.003,0.011,0.006,0.010,0.003,0.002,0.011],[0.044,0.017,0.027,0.037,0.024,0.016,0.079,0.010,0.259,0.006,0.009,0.032,0.023,0.009,0.022,0.012,0.064,0.031,0.026,0.010,0.019,0.007,0.034,0.004,0.021,0.002,0.007,0.086,0.005,0.018,0.011,0.011,0.003,0.003,0.011],[0.033,0.013,0.021,0.002,0.014,0.003,0.006,0.023,0.033,0.015,0.009,0.048,0.040,0.007,0.056,0.098,0.002,0.032,0.023,0.003,0.023,0.006,0.013,0.015,0.009,0.069,0.331,0.005,0.018,0.002,0.012,0.003,0.002,0.005,0.003],[0.017,0.004,0.002,0.000,0.096,0.008,0.095,0.007,0.004,0.003,0.013,0.012,0.045,0.006,0.017,0.013,0.002,0.016,0.029,0.007,0.360,0.023,0.045,0.023,0.005,0.004,0.018,0.008,0.005,0.010,0.042,0.011,0.013,0.032,0.007]]

KR8877J_6 = [[0.007,0.004,0.007,0.082,0.002,0.023,0.009,0.029,0.003,0.024,0.024,0.008,0.006,0.062,0.001,0.001,0.005,0.009,0.032,0.391,0.002,0.012,0.020,0.005,0.016,0.004,0.006,0.006,0.002,0.037,0.061,0.041,0.033,0.019,0.006],[0.004,0.004,0.008,0.078,0.001,0.013,0.005,0.059,0.002,0.044,0.041,0.006,0.005,0.052,0.001,0.001,0.002,0.008,0.036,0.366,0.001,0.010,0.015,0.003,0.011,0.008,0.008,0.005,0.004,0.015,0.074,0.035,0.045,0.023,0.007],[0.001,0.001,0.013,0.010,0.015,0.006,0.004,0.299,0.004,0.011,0.021,0.011,0.009,0.010,0.009,0.044,0.000,0.021,0.023,0.017,0.008,0.004,0.007,0.000,0.003,0.056,0.008,0.014,0.056,0.000,0.040,0.002,0.016,0.039,0.217],[0.021,0.011,0.022,0.060,0.018,0.026,0.090,0.014,0.234,0.005,0.011,0.025,0.016,0.009,0.015,0.011,0.052,0.030,0.029,0.015,0.019,0.007,0.030,0.003,0.016,0.001,0.003,0.134,0.006,0.013,0.011,0.014,0.004,0.005,0.020],[0.031,0.012,0.027,0.036,0.023,0.020,0.053,0.018,0.269,0.006,0.008,0.029,0.036,0.007,0.029,0.021,0.046,0.030,0.028,0.009,0.023,0.007,0.027,0.003,0.020,0.002,0.010,0.098,0.010,0.009,0.016,0.009,0.004,0.005,0.018],[0.036,0.019,0.017,0.002,0.027,0.004,0.009,0.027,0.063,0.012,0.008,0.045,0.035,0.006,0.050,0.140,0.002,0.036,0.030,0.003,0.031,0.004,0.017,0.016,0.007,0.055,0.239,0.007,0.018,0.002,0.014,0.004,0.003,0.006,0.004],[0.018,0.004,0.002,0.000,0.186,0.004,0.107,0.005,0.005,0.003,0.010,0.008,0.041,0.004,0.017,0.018,0.001,0.012,0.034,0.004,0.300,0.014,0.036,0.018,0.004,0.004,0.020,0.010,0.005,0.008,0.049,0.009,0.011,0.020,0.008]]

def readable(): #start = time.time() tags = [] for lst in DATA: index = max(enumerate(lst), key=lambda pair: pair[1])[0] tags.append(CATEGORIES[index]) tags.reverse() print(tags)

def construct(x):
    # x is what is passed in, so it is I basically, 
    #The rest is just your code 
    tag = []
    for lst in x:
        index = max(enumerate(lst), key=lambda pair: pair[1])[0]
        tag.append(CATEGORIES[index])
    tag.reverse()
    print(tag)

for i in (KR8877J_1,KR8877J_2,KR8877J_3,KR8877J_4,KR8877J_5,KR8877J_6):
    #pass in each list to the function, you can call i whatever you want, i is just an iterator.
    construct(i)
```

You can change `i` to `x` if it confuses you,

```
for x in (KR8877J_1,KR8877J_2,KR8877J_3,KR8877J_4,KR8877J_5,KR8877J_6):
    #pass in each list to the function, you can call i whatever you want, i is just an iterator.
    construct(x)
```

Comment: Can u explain it a little bit with comments? please! and Thank you!!

Comment: sorry maybe u know how to calculate from all 6 ['K', 'R', '8', '8', '7', 'J', 'J']
['K', 'R', '8', '8', '7', 'J', 'J']
['K', 'R', '8', '8', '7', 'J', 'J']
['K', 'R', '8', '8', 'J', '7', 'J']
['K', 'R', '8', '8', '7', 'J', 'J']
['K', 'R', '8', '8', '7', 'J', 'J'] - outputs the middle? I mean like use the most frequent letters - and find the average and most frequent combination of letters thank u? it will be the KR887JJ but I don't know hot to make it in python